# how I can get file owners with WinAPI c++

Tags: c++, security, winapi

please help me.
How I can get some file owner list with WinAPI?

-Administrator
-Sara
-SYSTEM
-Vahagn

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this article would help.

**"Finding the Owner of a File Object in C++"**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. They become useless when the referenced resource disappears. Please take the time to sum up the required steps, so that this answer remains valid in the future.